# Not able to execute god commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, god

I have setup `god` configuration at /`etc/init.d/god`.And installed gem god successfully when trying to get status of `god` using `god status` getting this issue.

```
find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem god (>= 0.a) with executable god (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you installing it through the Gemfile? Seems like a bundler related issue.